# Literature on bounds of Fubini's numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request, bell-numbers

If anybody can suggest where I can find a literature for a known upper and lower bounds on Fubini numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QING ZOU, "THE LOG-CONVEXITY OF THE FUBINI NUMBERS", http://toc.ui.ac.ir/article_21835_684378fec55e5c66c7fccd4321a84637.pdf

gives the bounds on $f_n$, the $n^{\text{th}}$ Fubini number:
$$  2^n < f_n < \frac{n!}{(\ln 2)^{n+1}} < (n+1)^n  \text{.}  $$
The lower bound holds for $n \geq 3$ and the upper for $n \geq 1$.

(Zou cites Barthelemy, "[AN ASYMPTOTIC EQUIVALENT FOR THE NUMBER OF TOTAL PREORDERS ON A FINITE SET](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X80901594) ",    from which we determine the intended base of the logarithm.)